# Some Buttons and Hover Effect Disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, local-storage

I created an onboarding walkthrough tour for use in a SaaS App that is being loaded with A/B testing software. The tour automatically begins on initial page load. The user can close the tour at any time. I have used localStorage so the browser will recall at what point the user exits the page and that tour will start again at the further point in the tour. I also have a "replay" button that is disabled when the tour is running and enabled when the tour is finished or closed. The replay button's selector is ".tstour-replay". I am animating the movement of the tour steps by adding a class that is using CSS3 @keyframes rules and then delaying the removal of the class so that the animation will repeat if the user goes back and uses that Next animation again. Those are referred to as "popover-ani1", "popover-ani2" and so on.

I am having an issue that is not consistently happening so I cannot find a pattern that explains why it's happening. Sometimes, the Next and Back buttons of the individual tour modals, referred to in the code as #popoverid1, #popoverid2, and so on or #popoverback1, #popoverback2, and so on, will be disabled. They do not respond to clicks and they both have CSS hover effects that do not work properly. However, the close button, .popover-close, always works. I cannot figure out why sometimes the Next and Back buttons are just completely unclickable and lose their interactivity while the Close button is always fine.

I am fairly new to JavaScript and jQuery. 
Here's my JavaScript code:

```
    function tourFunction() {

    $(".tstour-replay").addClass("tstour-replay-disable");
    $("#tstour-start").click(function(){
      //if clicked, do nothing
    });

  $("#popoverid1").click(function() {
    $(".popover1").addClass("popover1-ani").delay(200).fadeOut(50);
    $(".popover2").delay(250).fadeIn(50);
         setTimeout(function() {
         $(".popover1").removeClass("popover1-ani");
            }, 250);
});


 $("#popoverid2").click(function() {
   $(".popover2").fadeOut(50);
    $(".popover3").delay(50).fadeIn(50);
});

$("#popoverback2").click(function() {
  $(".popover2").addClass("popoverback2-ani").delay(200).fadeOut(50);
    $(".popover1").delay(250).fadeIn(50);
   setTimeout(function() {
         $(".popover2").removeClass("popoverback2-ani");
            }, 250);
});

$("#popoverid3").click(function() {
  $(".popover3").addClass("popover3-ani").delay(200).fadeOut(50);
    $(".popover4").delay(250).fadeIn(50);
          setTimeout(function() {
         $(".popover3").removeClass("popover3-ani");
            }, 250);
});


$("#popoverback3").click(function() {
  $(".popover3").addClass("popoverback3-ani").delay(200).fadeOut(50);
      $(".popover2").delay(250).fadeIn(50);
   setTimeout(function() {
         $(".popover3").removeClass("popoverback3-ani");
            }, 250);
});


$("#popoverid4").click(function() {
  $(".popover4").addClass("popover4-ani").delay(200).fadeOut(50);
    $(".popover5").delay(250).fadeIn(50);
          setTimeout(function() {
         $(".popover4").removeClass("popover4-ani");
            }, 250);
});


$("#popoverback4").click(function() {
  $(".popover4").addClass("popoverback4-ani").delay(200).fadeOut(50);
    $(".popover3").delay(250).fadeIn(50);
  setTimeout(function() {
         $(".popover4").removeClass("popoverback4-ani");
            }, 250);
});

$("#popoverid5").click(function() {
  $(".popover5").addClass("popover5-ani").delay(200).fadeOut(50);
    $(".popover6").delay(250).fadeIn(50);
          setTimeout(function() {
         $(".popover5").removeClass("popover5-ani");
            }, 250);
});

$("#popoverback5").click(function() {
  $(".popover5").addClass("popoverback5-ani").delay(200).fadeOut(50);
    $(".popover4").delay(250).fadeIn(50); 
  setTimeout(function() {
         $(".popover5").removeClass("popoverback5-ani");
            }, 250);
});

$("#popoverid6").click(function() {
  $(".popover6").addClass("popover6-ani").delay(200).fadeOut(50);
    $(".popover7").delay(250).fadeIn(50);
          setTimeout(function() {
         $(".popover6").removeClass("popover6-ani");
            }, 250);
});

$("#popoverback6").click(function() {
  $(".popover6").addClass("popoverback6-ani").delay(200).fadeOut(50);
   $(".popover5").delay(250).fadeIn(50);
  setTimeout(function() {
         $(".popover6").removeClass("popoverback6-ani");
            }, 250);  
});

}

function tourReplay() {
   $(".tstour-replay").removeClass("tstour-replay-disable");
     $("#tstour-start").click(function() {
          $(".tstour-replay").addClass("tstour-replay-disable");
            $(".popover1").fadeIn("fast");

  });
}

function disableTourReplay() {
   $(".tstour-replay").removeClass("tstour-replay-disable");
   $("#tstour-start").click(function() {
       //if clicked, do nothing
   });

}

//END FUNCTIONS

$(".popover-btn-start").click(function() {
  $(".tour-container").fadeOut();
  $(".popover7").fadeOut();
  $(".tstour-replay").removeClass("tstour-replay-disable");
       $("#tstour-start").click(function() {
             //if clicked, do nothing
       });
     tourReplay();
});

$(".popover-close").click(function(){
    $(".tour-container").fadeOut();
    $(".popover").fadeOut();
     tourReplay();
});

//BEGIN FUNCTION TRIGGERS

var trigger_flag = localStorage.getItem('tstour');


if (!trigger_flag) {

      disableTourReplay();
      $(".popover1").fadeIn("fast"); 
        tourFunction(); 


} else if (trigger_flag == '1') { //clicked next1

     disableTourReplay();
     $(".popover2").fadeIn("fast");
         tourFunction(); 



} else if (trigger_flag == '2') { //clicked next2
     disableTourReplay();
     $(".popover3").fadeIn("fast");
       tourFunction(); 


} else if (trigger_flag == '3') { //clicked next3
      disableTourReplay();
     $(".popover4").fadeIn("fast");
         tourFunction(); 



} else if (trigger_flag == '4') { //clicked next4

    disableTourReplay();
     $(".popover5").fadeIn("fast");
       tourFunction(); 


} else if (trigger_flag == '5') { //clicked next5

     disableTourReplay(); 
     $(".popover6").fadeIn("fast");
       tourFunction(); 


} else if (trigger_flag == '6' || '7') {  //got to last popover, finished tour or closed out
    tourReplay();
}

//END FUNCTION TRIGGERS  

//BEGIN LOCAL STORAGE SET

$(document).on("click", "#popoverid1", function(e){ 
    localStorage.setItem('tstour', '1');
});

$(document).on("click", "#popoverid2", function(e){
    localStorage.setItem('tstour', '2');
});

$(document).on("click", "#popoverid3", function(e){
    localStorage.setItem('tstour', '3');
});

$(document).on("click", "#popoverid4", function(e){
    localStorage.setItem('tstour', '4');
});

$(document).on("click", "#popoverid5", function(e){
    localStorage.setItem('tstour', '5');
});

$(document).on("click", "#popoverid6", function(e){
    localStorage.setItem('tstour', '6');
});

$(document).on("click", ".popover-btn-start", function(e){
    localStorage.setItem('tstour', '7');
});

$(document).on("click", ".popover-close", function(e){
    localStorage.setItem('tstour', '7');
});
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div class="tour-centered">

  <div id="tstour-start" class="tstour-replay">How Does This Work?</div>

    <div class="popover popover1">
      <div class="popover-right">
        <div id="popover-close" class="popover-close">
            </div>
        <div class="popover-content">
          <div class="popover-title">Employees On Your Calendar</div>
          <div class="popover-body">Here's Jane Deaux, a sample employee. I preloaded some events for her in your calendar.</div>
          <div class="popover-footer">
            <div class="popover-progress">1 of 6</div>
            <div class="popover-buttons">
              <div class="popover-next" id="popoverid1">Next</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="popover popover2">
      <div class="popover-above">
        <div id="popover-close" class="popover-close">
               </div>
        <div class="popover-content">
          <div class="popover-title">Calendar Events</div>
          <div class="popover-body">Notice Jane's name on the calendar. Each listing is a scheduled or pending calendar event.
            <br />
            <br />Hover your mouse over her name to quickly see the event details.</div>
          <div class="popover-footer">
            <div class="popover-progress">2 of 6</div>
            <div class="popover-buttons">
              <div class="popover-back" id="popoverback2">Back</div>
              <div class="popover-next" id="popoverid2">Next</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="popover popover3">
      <div class="popover-above">
        <div id="popover-close" class="popover-close">
               </div>
        <div class="popover-content">
          <div class="popover-title">Add a New Calendar Event</div>
          <div class="popover-body">Double-click on any day to create a new calendar event. Use Jane to try it out and deduct hours from her time-off banks.

           <br /><br />Give it a try. I'll wait right here until you're done.<br /></div>
          <div class="popover-footer">
            <div class="popover-progress">3 of 6</div>
            <div class="popover-buttons">
              <div class="popover-back" id="popoverback3">Back</div>
              <div class="popover-next" id="popoverid3">Next</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="popover popover4">
      <div class="popover-below">
        <div id="popover-close" class="popover-close">
             </div>
        <div class="popover-content">
          <div class="popover-title">Create More Calendar Events</div>
          <div class="popover-body">Great job! You can also click this icon to create more calendar events.</div>
          <div class="popover-footer">
            <div class="popover-progress">4 of 6</div>
            <div class="popover-buttons">
              <div class="popover-back" id="popoverback4">Back</div>
              <div class="popover-next" id="popoverid4">Next</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="popover popover5">
      <div class="popover-below">
        <div id="popover-close" class="popover-close">
                </div>
        <div class="popover-content">
          <div class="popover-title">Customize Your Calendar</div>
          <div class="popover-body">Visit Preferences to customize your calendar event codes, create time-off plans, and much more.</div>
          <div class="popover-footer">
            <div class="popover-progress">5 of 6</div>
            <div class="popover-buttons">
              <div class="popover-back" id="popoverback5">Back</div>
              <div class="popover-next" id="popoverid5">Next</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="popover popover6">
      <div class="popover-below">
        <div id="popover-close" class="popover-close">
                </div>
        <div class="popover-content">
          <div class="popover-title">Add More Employees</div>
          <div class="popover-body">When you're ready, add more of your employees and create calendar events for them.
            <br />
            <br />The more employees you load and track, the easier it is to avoid scheduling conflicts.</div>
          <div class="popover-footer">
            <div class="popover-progress">6 of 6</div>
            <div class="popover-buttons">
              <div class="popover-back" id="popoverback6">Back</div>
              <div class="popover-next" id="popoverid6">Next</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="popover popover7">
      <div class="popover-content-final">
        <div class="popover-title-final">Ready to Take Back Your Time?</div>
        <div class="popover-btn-start">Start Tracking!</div>
        <div class="popover-help">
          <a href="https://tracksmart.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new" target="_blank">
      I Need Some Help
      </a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your html structure as well please? I'm assuming all the js code is wrapped inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ... your code ... });`?

Comment: I added the HTML. The A/B testing software will automatically add on $(document).ready(function() { ... your code ... }); so I do not have to write those parts myself.

Comment: can you try replacing all the click functions with .on("click",function(){.....})

Comment: I did try that, and then the Next button didn't work at all. I was binding the event to the document though. Are you suggesting binding the function to the handler instead? Like $("#popoverid1").on("click",function(){.....}) instead of $("#popoverid1").click(function(){.....}). And just to help me understand better, other than the difference in syntax what does the on function do differently than click?

Comment: There's no difference between element.on('click') and element.click, it's just a shortcut/syntactic sugar. You can bind more than one event at the same time by using element.on(), so it has its uses. I've been looking for the issue, but can't find it immediately. Is this fiddle representative for the problem? https://jsfiddle.net/z1n8uavq/

Comment: The fiddle doesn't have the issue. It works fine. I am watching user sessions interacting with the tour and I've been able to identify a pattern that sets off the dead buttons and now I can even produce the issue in my browser. Tour loads > click .popover-close > browse to another page > come back to tour > click #tstour-replay (the replay button) > .popover-next (the next button) is dead. Any ideas?

Comment: I found the problem. It was with trigger_flag == '6' || '7'. There is the tourReplay(); function but I left out the tourFunction(); function, which contains all the click events and left the next button dead upon tour replay from closing the tour. Thanks everyone for your input and help!